# Target Chrome and safari, but not Safari on iphone or ipads?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

Is there anyway (with CSS only) to target chrome and safari, but not safari on the iphone or ipads?

Answer (score 1):

you can use media queries:

CSS2:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 1024px)" href="desktop.css" type="text/css" />
```

CSS3:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and not handheld" href="desktop.css" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

What about specifying it with css [media](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html).